# Take row names from list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, variables, purrr, r-rownames

Starting from a list of lists like **outcome**:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
month <- c(3,4,2,1,5,7,3,1,8,9)
preds <- c(0.5,0.1,0.15,0.23,0.75,0.6,0.49,0.81,0.37,0.14)

l_1 <- data.frame(id, preds, month)

preds <- c(0.45,0.18,0.35,0.63,0.25,0.63,0.29,0.11,0.17,0.24)

l_2 <- data.frame(id, preds, month)

preds <- c(0.58,0.13,0.55,0.13,0.76,0.3,0.29,0.81,0.27,0.04)

l_3 <- data.frame(id, preds, month)

preds <- c(0.3,0.61,0.18,0.29,0.85,0.76,0.56,0.91,0.48,0.91)

l_4 <- data.frame(id, preds, month)

outcome <- list(l_1, l_2, l_3, l_4)
```

My interest is to take the assigned unique **row values** and create a new variable as if we do:

```
sample <- outcome[[1]]
sample$unique_id <- rownames(sample)
```

However, I don´t want to go manually because my list has 100 lists.
Moreover, I don´t want to assign values manually to each row because I want to preserve the row names generated by R. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `lapply`

```
lapply(outcome, function(x) {
  x$unique_id <- rownames(x)
  x
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

With `lapply` and `cbind`:

```
lapply(outcome, function(x) {
  cbind(unique_id=rownames(x), x)
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

We may also use `rownames_to_column`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
map(outcome, ~ .x %>%
    rownames_to_column('unique_id'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another base R option is to use `Map`

```
Map(function(x){
  x$unique_id <- rownames(x)
  x
}, outcome)
```